# How can I use bound values in an SQL statement that uses LIKE?

Tags: php, sqlite

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
public function searchCustomer($searchString)
//---------------------------------------------------------
{
    $stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT
                                cu_firstname, cu_lastname, id_customer
                            FROM
                                t_customers
                            WHERE 
                                cu_firstname LIKE '%:token%'
                            OR
                                cu_lastname LIKE '%:token%'
                            ;");

    $stmt->bindValue(":token", $searchString, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;    
}
```

This code does not work, since `:token` is apparently ignored. The only way I have found to make it work is to directly use `$searchString` between the percent signs.

How do I do this correctly or are bound parameters not allowed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add % around the search string, not around the parameter

```
QUERY ... LIKE :token

$stmt->bindValue(":token", '%' . $searchString . '%', SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    public function searchCustomer($searchString)
//---------------------------------------------------------
{
    $stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT
                                cu_firstname, cu_lastname, id_customer
                            FROM
                                t_customers
                            WHERE 
                                cu_firstname LIKE ':token'
                            OR
                                cu_lastname LIKE ':token'
                            ;");

    $stmt->bindValue(":token", '%'.$searchString. '%', SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;    
}
```